# Issue with HTML display format?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

In my application I need to select the image. So I use input tag of type "file". The UI looks like the following image,

```
<input type="file" id="fileUploader">
```

[image]

How can I write the above input tag as `<a>` tag so that when clicking on the camera image I need to select the file,

```
<a href="#" onClick='#'><img src="img/camera.jpg"/></a>
```

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/X23dx/253/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $(function(){ 
     $('#anchorlink').click(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith('<input type="file" id="fileUploader" />'); 
$('#fileUploader').click(); 
    })
    });




<a href="#" id="anchorlink" >click<img src="stylish.png"/></a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dQHh5/3/

Comment: I don't need show/Hide method. I need Onclick of image I need to select file, No need of again clicking the browse button

Comment: use $('#fileUploader').click(); with this auto file selected.

Answer (score 1):

Try like below for change the default file picker using jquery mobile

HTML is like:

```
<span class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-corner-all fileinput-button">
<span>Pick File </span>
<input type="file" name="files" multiple data-role="none"/>
</span>
```

css is Like:

```
.fileinput-button {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 4px;
    }
.fileinput-button input {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      filter: alpha(opacity=0);
      transform: translate(-300px, 0) scale(4);
      font-size: 23px;
      direction: ltr;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X23dx/253/)

Answer (score 0):

A better option than `a` would be to use a `label` with `for`, and keep the `input` hidden.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/GpsAJ/***

*Markup*:

```
<label for="fileUploader" />
<input type="file" id="fileUploader" />
```

*CSS*:

```
#fileUploader {
    display: none;
}
label[for=fileUploader] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 128px; height: 128px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url('your-camera-image-here') no-repeat left center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is what you need

```
<img onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('myFile').click();" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/O/r/K/T/t/n/camera-icon-hi.png" style="width:50px;height:auto" />

<input type="file" id="myFile" style="display:none" />
```

I just hide my input file and let the `onclick` attribute of image show the dialog..

Just refer to my sample below.

http://jsfiddle.net/fbB46/